# Calculating wheel and motor size for run-of-river hydroelectric generator

Tags: water, renewables, electricity-generation

I am a student designing a hydro electric generator used on rivers to collect kinetic energy from horizontal water flow, rather than potential energy from vertical water drops.

My idea is to turn a large wheel using the water flow, this is connected to a smaller wheel using a belt in order to increase RPM.

It is used solely to charge as many 17Ah 12V batteries as possible from the power generated.

A generator I have been looking at in particular is this: [1.3kw single-phase motor, 3400 RPM, 110VAC, 15.3A](http://www.ebay.com/itm/ESTA-Absaugtechnik-1-3kw-Single-Phase-Motor-B5-Flange-3400-RPM-110V-15-3A-/201450161121?hash=item2ee75d83e1:g:TjMAAOSwT5tWITJ7).

Here are my calculations:

- Water velocity = 2m/s, big wheel circumference = 75cm
- This gives 2.66 RPS which is 160RPM
- to reach the 3400 RPM of the motor the small wheel must be (3400/160) = 21.25 times smaller
- this means the circumference of the small wheel is (75cm /21.25) = 3.59cm
- this in turn means the diameter is (3.59/pi) = 1.12cm

It seems like this is a very small wheel to be turning such a large motor. Is this diameter too small to function correctly?

Comment: Welcome to Sustainability.SE! I edited your question and title a bit to make it more clear. However, I'm concerned this may not be a good fit on this site, and may do better over on [Electronics.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). But, let's leave it for a bit and see if anyone here has some insight.

Comment: My guess is that yes, that would be much too small. A belt would slip probably. This question may also be a good fit for http://engineering.stackexchange.com/ as they could likely suggest a solution...

Comment: How is this question different from one [recently posted](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14045/how-to-calculate-hydropower-in-kw-without-water-head) on SE Engineering?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a better fit on engineering.SE, where it has already been discussed: http://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/14045